# Multiple switch cases executing with break in each case

Tags: switch-statement, case

I have included just a part of code. When I tried debugging this code. I see after completion of `LINE_TYP` case, code jumps `POINT_TYP` case as well though break command is used ? I don't know why. The function `ev03u0()` doesnt have return anywhere within the code.

```
  switch(curve->crv_type)
    { 
            case POINT_TYP:
            point = ev02u0(entity);
            if (!point)
            {
                evfree ((char *)curve,"evcrvu:1.1");
                return ( (CURVE *) NULL );
            }
            curve->crv_data = (PVOID)point;
            break;
    case LINE_TYP:
        line = ev03u0(entity);
        if (!line)
        {
            evfree ((char *)curve,"evcrvu:1.1");
            return ( (CURVE *) NULL );
        }
        curve->crv_data = (PVOID)line;
        break;
```

I am novice to coding.

Comment: Do you mean that when `curve->crv_type` is something else than POINT_TYP, it jumps from the first case statement to the second?

Comment: Can you please provide little more code so that we can answer it properly